# Can a 4-hole harmonica play this song?

Tags: harmonica

I have a [4-hole harmonica](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Buy-Huang-Harmonica-Holes-Yellow/dp/B00IMZI3QS). It is too simple; so, I can play 
simple songs only.

Now, I want to know: "Is there any way to play [this song](http://www.dinh.dk/pdf/xinthoigianquamau-lp.pdf) with my own harmonica?".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific to be useful to other users.  I see you've asked about the range in another question, though, which is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems. The harp is most likely diatonic, and has a major scale playable, with an octave - 8 notes- range. The song has a range of 10 notes, so the highest two COULD be played an octave lower, but it will sound strange. Another problem is that since it's diatonic, but the song is in a minor key, the bottom two notes in the song will be missing from the harp. This could give you all the other (higher) notes, but the lower two would have to be played an octave higher. Again, strange. Another problem is that , because it's in a minor key, the leading note is sharpened. You won't find this note on that harp. It won't matter what key it's transposed into, that note won't play.

Comment: I think you can bend the note up though.

Comment: @JacobSwanson - it's more usual to bend notes down, so, maybe the tonic could make it happen. But it's easier to bend when drawing, so on note 6 it could work! That just leaves the bottom two notes missing.

Comment: @0mf Try just looking up "bending a note on a harmonica"